# Displaying a Cypher property in Neo4j browser: What is the difference between these two queries?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am a Neo4j beginner and grateful for the Neo4j browser to show visualisations. I am using Neo4j 2.2 because it's the version being [used in the book I'm following along with](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Building-Web-Applications-Python-Neo4j/dp/1783983981)

Please help me try to understand if I have a syntax error or more specifically, if there's a gap in my understanding about how nodes are created.

I would like to achieve this:

[image]

**Creating Node - Matthew**

As you can see node 'Matthew' has the name overlaid on top of it. Hovering over, and you see the properties and labels. Note the property 'Name'
[image]

I used this Cypher query to create it

`CREATE (matthew:MALE:STUDENT {Name:'Matthew', surname:'Cooper',age:36, country:'US'});`

**Creating Node - Lisa**

Node Lisa has the name overlaid on it too. If you hover over you see
[image]

I used the following Cypher query

`CREATE (lisa:FEMALE {name:'Lisa', surname:'Adams', age:15, country:'Canada'});`

**The Question**

Note that the name property in the Matthew query is spelt with Sentence case ie `Name` and the Lisa query is spelt in lower case `name` If I create a Lisa node with sentence case, the name won't be overlaid over the top. Why is this? I would have thought they'd be the same. What's the difference between 'Name' and 'name' Are cypher query properties case-sensitive?

Here is a screenshot of executing the Lisa cypher query using the same spelling of the *name* and the property isn't overlaid on the node in the visualisation.

[image]

Comment: Attribute names and values are case sensitive in Neo4j. 

I expect the reason it does not show up after the fact is that the display property for the `FEMALE` labels is not set properly. Click on the `FEMALE` label at the top of the browser so you can set the display property for that particular label at the bottom.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Quite why 
I needed to explicitly set that in the UI I don't know. It was set by default/automagically for the Male label.
Thank you!

Comment: It was probably auto-correlated to something else the first time you created the `FEMALE` node. It would then remain that way until you switched it after the fact.

Comment: Thanks Dave. His first was the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Cypher properties are case sensitive.

It uses a heuristic on which attributes to show as caption and stores that in the styling, which you can see with `:style`.

You can download and edit and upload that file again or override it with a command like this

```
:style 
node { color: ... }
...
```

In the `caption` attribute you see which property is used.

see also: https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/#_styling_neo4j_browser_visualization